# Motorcycle: Puncture in tubeless tire. OK to plug yourself?

Tags: motorcycle, tires

I got a nail in my tire the other day. Its wedged in the tire so tightly that the tire isnt actually losing pressure. A friend told me I could fix it myself by using a kind of volcanised rubber glue in a syringe to plug the hole.

It was my understanding that this was only a temporary fix to get you out of a trouble if you are in the middle of no where, but my friend insists it can be a permanent fix.

Has anyone had any experience with this?

Comment: You will hear from camp that if you plug a motorcycle tire your bike will explode into a fireball and you will be killed. The other camp has actually plugged tires and their bikes did not explode into that fireball and kill them like camp one said it would. The truth is you can’t find anyone who has witnessed a crash caused by a tire plug failing, oh you hart that my friends sisters boyfriend knew a guy whose uncle once heard that if you plug motorcycle tire it will cause the motorcycle to explode. The truth is many people plug motorcycle tires and never have a problem and ride the plugged tir

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The original tubeless tire plug consisted of a small piece of heavy twine that was impregnated with a self vulcanizing adhesive. It was inserted with a forked tool from the tread side of the tire. Over the years they have fallen out of favor and in many locations are illegal. They rope plugs have been replaced by a mushroom shaped plug. The new plug is inserted from the interior of the tire. the larger piece acts as a patch and the stem plugs the hole. The top of the plug is too large to fit thru the puncture. This greatly reduces the chance of catastophic failure that was possible with the rope plugs. In your case I would take the chance and use them for an emergency repair. Reduce your speed and ride with caution until you can have it properly repaired.

Comment: Use the repair suggested here to get yourself to a mechanic, and get the tyre replaced immediately. Repairs rarely work properly on motorbike tyres, and with both tyres critical to proper balance, it's risky

Answer (score 6):

Please, just buy a new tire. Don't ever ride your motorcycle on a tire that is damaged in any way. Don't try to save a few bucks when you're on a motorcycle and you only have two tires between you and the ground, it could end up costing you your life.

Comment: On 4 wheels you can get away with it, but having a compromised tire on two wheels is a needless risk. (dont be a statistic)

Comment: +1. I'm a bit of a stingy guy and it took a lot for me to break down and buy a new tire after I got a small puncture in one that I'd just bought a week earlier. But, I finally rationalized it as such - you know what costs a lot more than a new tire? A casket. And your loved ones get stuck with the bill for the latter.

Answer (score 2):

I am yet to own a bike with tubeless tyres meself, but I did have some punctures, and consequently researched if I could go tubeless so as to be able to do easier repairs on the side of the road. And while there are no consensus (you put two gear-heads together and get three opinions out of them on this subject), one argument I had seen time and time again is that you only have two wheels, and it is some added risk you would have to make a decision about. Catastrophic failure of one motorcycle tyre could be a lot more dangerous than the same thing happening to one or even two car wheels.

I do not dismiss the idea of long-term repairs of motorcycle tubeless tyres as yet, and I know that those could be quite expensive, but you may want err on the side of caution.